# How to save and generate excel file and save in server

Tags: php, excel, header, zip

I've to generate zip file by php in that file there are few resume and 1 excel file
I successfully add that resumes but unable to add excel because that excel file is also php file which generate excel so i want code to save that excel file on server so i can include in my zip file its all dynamic so i'm confused how can it happens when someone click on download zip file and get that excel file also in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you execute your script that make the excel file (you save the temp file somewhere)
and then you execute your "zip" script

if you cannot concat the two scripts in one, you always can execute the first one by using file_get_content() like that (fopen must be enabled on your server) :

```
$my_excel_content = file_get_content("http://myserver/make_excel.php?parameters=...");
$my_excel_filename = "/tmp/".md5(session_id().microtime(TRUE)).".xls";
file_put_content($my_excel_filename,$my_excel_content);

$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ( $zip->open("myzip.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) ) {
    $zip->addFile($my_excel_filename , "the-excel-file.xls");
}
$zip->close();
```

Comment: @pekka okay well actually i'm new here so don't know much about it