# how to generate and save excel file to server?

Tags: php, excel, file, http-headers, content-disposition

I'm trying to generate an excel file and directly save it on my web server (PHP) with this code:

```php
$content = '"ColHeader1"'."\t".'"ColHeader2"'."\t".'"ColHeader3"'."\t"
  . "\n"
  . '"lorem ipsum"'."\t".'"dolor sit amet"'."\t".'"consectetur lorat"'."\t"."\n"
  . '"pew pew pew"'."\t".'"gun shot"'."\t".'"and Bang!!"'."\t"."\n"
  ;

$filedir = './assets/doc/';
$filename = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
$filepath = realpath($filedir . $filename . '.xls');

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='".$filepath."'");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo $content . "\n";
```

the problems I need help with are:

- the offered filename doesn't have any file extension even though I already put `.xls` in the `$filepath`
- it only creates the file on my local computer instead of the server

can anyone help me with these? can those 2 points actually be done?

I've read [How to save and generate excel file and save in server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7077750/1235167) but I have no idea what to do with it or how to implement it to my code.

I've also read [Generate Excel file, but do not save to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20676839/1235167) but if possible, I'd like to use just pure PHP..

Comment: I found out that `file_put_contents()` does exactly these 2 things. so silly of me. I think this short comment is the answer.. should I use the Answer Your Question button instead?